# How should I format GET data in an anchor href?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I'm validating my web pages with W3C's validator, and it gives me the following error when I try to use GET variables in my hyperlinks:

> & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &.)

I'm using the standard format:

```
... href='url.php?var1=val1&var2=val2' ...
```

It's throwing this error numerous times with links from my affiliate programs, as well. Should I just ignore this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should encode the ampersands as they have special meaning in HTML:

```
... href='url.php?var1=val1&amp;var2=val2' ...
```

In general browsers cope pretty well with unencoded ampersands, but it's good practise to encode them.

Answer (score 0):

`&` should be `&amp;`. You can entity escape your strings by passing them to [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
... href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( 'url.php?var1=val1&var2=val2', ENT_QUOTES ); ?>" ...
```